# How to parse through json file and transform it into time series

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

I have this json file:

```
    {
  "walk": [
    {
      "date": "2021-01-10",
      "duration": 301800,
      "levels": {
        "data": [
          {
            "timestamp": "2021-01-10T13:16:00.000",
            "level": "slow",
            "seconds": 360
          },
          {
            "timestamp": "2021-01-10T13:22:00.000",
            "level": "moderate",
            "seconds": 2940
          },
          {
            "dateTime": "2021-01-10T14:11:00.000",
            "level": "fast",
            "seconds": 300
```

and I want to parse through this such that it is a 1-min level time series data. (i.e.: 6 data points (360 seconds= 6 minutes) as level "slow".

```
timestamp              level   
2021-01-10 13:16:00     slow
2021-01-10 13:17:00     slow
.......
2021-01-10 13:22:00     moderate
```

I have right now:

```
with open('walks.json') as f:
df = pd.json_normalize(json.load(f), 
                       record_path=['walk']
                      )
```

but that returns levels nested in one cell for each day. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to nest the record_path levels

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data=data, record_path=["walk", ["levels", "data"]])
```